# AVAssetExportSession make black video sometimes

Tags: swift3, overlay, video-processing, avassetexportsession

I'm new baby for Video Processing use Swift 3. I try to merge multiple videos with `AVAssetExportSession`, and using `AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool` to add overlay for final video.

The problem is sometimes the final video is perfect, but sometimes it just give me a black video with sound only even I didn't change anything :(

Anybody who ran into that problem same me please give an idea, thanks!

```
let mixComposition: AVMutableComposition = AVMutableComposition()

//Add assets here

let mainComposition: AVMutableVideoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition(propertiesOf: mixComposition)
mainComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30)
mainComposition.renderSize = renderSize
mainComposition.renderScale = 1.0
mainComposition.animationTool = AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool(postProcessingAsVideoLayer: videoLayer, in: parentLayer)
mainComposition.instructions = instructions

let exportSession: AVAssetExportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: mixComposition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)!
exportSession.videoComposition = mainComposition
exportSession.audioMix = audioMix
exportSession.outputURL = outputURL
exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4
exportSession.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true

exportSession.exportAsynchronously {
    // Ended here
}
```

Comment: What I did is try waiting for couple seconds after exported video, seems like the exported video not ready to play! 

Comment: I am facing same issue. Did you find solution?